# Unable to select GridView item

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm trying to **highlight background** of one `GridView` element.

Activity.java:

```
private CustomAdapter ca;

public void onCreate(Bundle _) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    // ...

    GridView gw = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gw.setAdapter(ca = new CustomAdapter(this));
    gw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // attempt 1:
            view.setSelection(true);

            // attempt 2:
            gw.setSelection(position);

            // attempt 3:
            gw.setItemChecked(position, true);

            // tried everything WITH and WITHOUT this:
            ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Download items async, and call...
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        // ... in a callback
    }

    // getItem(), getCount() and getItemId() implemented here

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if( convertView!=null ) view = convertView;
        else {
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);

          // calculate height so that an item is a square
          int height = parent.getHeight();
          if( height>0 ) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height/3;
          }
        }

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageBitmap( getItemImageBitmap(position) );
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_layout.xml

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
          android:numColumns="3"


          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_selector" 

          />
<!-- I've tried any combination of those last three params I could think of -->
```

grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

grid_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

I tried putting `grid_selector` as item background OR as `listSelector` attribute in GridView.

My goal is to have **one** item highlighted upon user click (and after until other item is selected).

Comment: take a look at the documentation for setItemChecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the magic combination for me was:

1. **`gw.setItemChecked(position, true);`** in `Activity.java` is enough,
2. **No changes** in `CustomAdapter.java`,
3. `listSelector="@drawable/grid_selector"` **MUST be removed** from `activity_layout.xml`,
4. `grid_item.xml` must have **background**,
5. **Use `android:state_checked="true"`** instead of `android:state_selected="true"` in `grid_selector.xml`.

Comment: with setChoiceMode() the grid should be able to handle the checking itself.

Comment: I think custom adapter blocks it.

Comment: yeah, you would probably need the root of the grid item to handle the checked state.

Comment: Yes, and I believe that's what I'm doing setting `grid_item.xml` root item's background to `grid_selector.xml` :)